# Snowflake connection string using azureAd

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using azureAd for snowflake authentication.  I am working with snowflake.data and c# to access the data. What should i used in my connection string to indicate azureAd?

Edit:
I am trying to access snowflake through the c# api not a browser.
Here is the code I did not  add before:

```cs
using Snowflake.Data.Client;


var connectString = "schema=CustomerDATA;port=443;WAREHOUSE=CUSTOMER_WH;ROLE=ANALYST;db=YES;";

using (var conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = connectString;
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select top 100 * from Customers;";
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

when the program tries to open the connection, it complains about missing properties in the connection string like user, account, and password.   Is there a different way to open the connection in c# where I use Azure AD?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I am facing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, no.  We have been using a single service account for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly does "indicate AzureAD" implies. If you are using AzureAD as the IDP for authentication then you can use either 'externalbrowser' as the authenticator or OAuth mechanism for token based login / authentication.

The code does not have any user credentials to authenticate the user to Snowflake.

Add the following 2 parameters in the connection string where other parameters like db, wh etc are passed:

```
user='<AD Username>'
authenticator='externalbrowser'
```

So, with this when you now run the code, a browser window will open and you can authenticate with the AD user credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using one of the supported Snowflake drivers/connectors from c# client to connect Snowflake. To set up Azure AD browser-based SSO for authentication, set the authenticator login parameter/option to externalbrowser for the client. The below document covers the details about setting externalbrowser for the supported drivers.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#setting-up-browser-based-sso

For example, If you are using ODBC (Windows)driver then

In the ODBC Data Source Administrator tool, edit the DSN for Snowflake and set Authenticator to externalbrowser.

If you are using .NET driver then you can set authenticator=externalbrowser in the connection string for the driver.